# Enabled View after login my application

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, mvvm

I am a beginner in WPF /MVVM and I have a lot of problems.. 
One of theses, it that I've an application with a LoginView on the left and a content view on the left.
Theses 2 views are in the MainView like this :
First View "MainWindow"

```
<Window x:Class="MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:iut1"
    xmlns:ctrls="clr-namespace:iut1.Views"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    Title="Outil de pilotage SCR" Height="650" Width="950"
    WindowStartupLocation="CenterScreen"
    DataContext="{Binding Path=MainWindowViewModel, Mode=OneWay, Source={StaticResource Locator}}">
<Grid>
    <Viewbox Name="vbxConnexion" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="623" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="224">
        <ctrls:ConnexionView></ctrls:ConnexionView>
    </Viewbox>
    <Viewbox Name="vbxContenu" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="233,0,0,0" Width="682" VerticalAlignment="Top"  RenderTransformOrigin="0.5,0.5" Height="620" Stretch="None">
        <ctrls:MigrationModeleView IsEnabled="{Binding EnabledView}" Height="623" Width="653" ></ctrls:MigrationModeleView>
    </Viewbox>


</Grid>
```

Seconde View : "ConnexionView"

```
<UserControl x:Class="iut1.Views.ConnexionView"
         xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
         xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
         xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
         xmlns:local="clr-namespace:iut1.Views"
         xmlns:w="clr-namespace:iut1.Classes"
         mc:Ignorable="d" 
         d:DesignHeight="720" d:DesignWidth="240"
          DataContext="{Binding Path=MainWindowViewModel, Mode=OneWay, Source={StaticResource Locator}}">
<UserControl.Resources>
    <w:EnumMatchToBooleanConverter x:Key="enumConverter" />
</UserControl.Resources>
<Grid Margin="10,30,-13,-18">

    <GroupBox x:Name="gpbSource" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="6,10,0,386" Width="220" Header="Environnement source" Background="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.ScrollBarBrushKey}}" >
        <Grid Margin="0,0,0,20">
            <!--<Rectangle Fill="#FFF4F4F5" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="317" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="220" RadiusY="5" RadiusX="5" Stroke="Black" Opacity="0.1" Margin="0,5,0,0"/>-->
            <Label x:Name="lblIdentifiant" Content="Identifiant de l'utilisateur :" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="4,24,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="200"/>

            <TextBox x:Name="txtNomUsager" Text="{Binding IdUtilisateur}" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="23" Margin="4,48,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="200" AutomationProperties.IsRequiredForForm="True" BorderThickness="2">
            </TextBox>

            <Label x:Name="Password" Content="Mot de passe :" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="4,80,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="200"/>
            <PasswordBox x:Name="txtMotDePasse" w:PasswordHelper.Attach="True" w:PasswordHelper.Password="{Binding PasswordUtilisateur, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="23" Margin="4,103,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="200"/>
            <RadioButton x:Name="rdbUnit" IsChecked="{Binding Path=EnvironnementSource, Mode=TwoWay,Converter={StaticResource enumConverter}, ConverterParameter=Unitaire}" GroupName="envSource" Width="79" Content="Unitaire" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="4,160,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top"/>
            <RadioButton x:Name="rdbFonctionnel" IsChecked="{Binding Path=EnvironnementSource, Mode=TwoWay,Converter={StaticResource enumConverter}, ConverterParameter=Fonctionnel}" Content="Fonctionnel" GroupName="envSource" Width="79" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="4,183,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top"/>
            <RadioButton x:Name="rdbIntegre" IsChecked="{Binding Path=EnvironnementSource, Mode=TwoWay,Converter={StaticResource enumConverter}, ConverterParameter=Integre}" GroupName="envSource" Width="79" Content="Intégré" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="4,206,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top"/>
            <RadioButton x:Name="rdbAcceptation" IsChecked="{Binding Path=EnvironnementSource, Mode=TwoWay,Converter={StaticResource enumConverter}, ConverterParameter=Acceptation}" GroupName="envSource" Width="90" Content="Acceptation" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="114,162,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top"/>
            <RadioButton x:Name="rdbFormation" IsChecked="{Binding Path=EnvironnementSource, Mode=TwoWay,Converter={StaticResource enumConverter}, ConverterParameter=Formation}" GroupName="envSource" Width="90" Content="Formation" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="114,183,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top"/>
            <RadioButton x:Name="rdbProduction" IsChecked="{Binding Path=EnvironnementSource, Mode=TwoWay,Converter={StaticResource enumConverter}, ConverterParameter=Production}" GroupName="envSource" Width="90" Content="Production" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="114,206,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top"/>
            <Button x:Name="Login" Content="Connexion" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="4,252,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="200" Command="{Binding ButtonCommand}"/>
        </Grid>
    </GroupBox>

    <!--<Rectangle Fill="#FFF4F4F5" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="317" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="220" RadiusY="5" RadiusX="5" Stroke="Black" Opacity="0.1" Margin="0,350,0,-179"/>-->
    <GroupBox Width="220"  Header="Environnement source" Margin="6,338,17,57" IsEnabled="False" Background="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.ScrollBarBrushKey}}">
        <Grid Margin="0,0,0,20">
            <Label x:Name="lblIdentifiantCopie" Content="Identifiant de l'utilisateur :" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="4,24,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="200"/>
            <TextBox x:Name="txtNomUsagerCopie" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="23" Margin="4,47,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="200"/>
            <Label x:Name="lblMotDePasseCopie" Content="Mot de passe :" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="4,80,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="200"/>
            <PasswordBox x:Name="txtMotDePasseCopie" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="23" Margin="4,103,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="200"/>
            <RadioButton x:Name="rdbUnitCopie"  Width="79" Content="Unitaire" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="4,160,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top"/>
            <RadioButton x:Name="rdbFonctionnelCopie"  Width="79" Content="Fonctionnel" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="4,183,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top"/>
            <RadioButton x:Name="rdbIntegreCopie"  Width="79" Content="Intégré" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="4,206,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top"/>
            <RadioButton x:Name="rdbAcceptationCopie" Width="90" Content="Acceptation" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="114,162,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top"/>
            <RadioButton x:Name="rdbFormationCopie"  Width="90" Content="Formation" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="114,183,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top"/>
            <RadioButton x:Name="rdbProductionCopie"   Width="90" Content="Production" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="114,206,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top"/>
            <Button x:Name="btnAjout" Content="Ajouter dans l'environnement" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="4,252,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="200"/>
        </Grid>
    </GroupBox>


</Grid>
```

MigrationModelView

```
<UserControl x:Class="iut1.Views.MigrationModeleView"
         xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
         xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
         xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
         xmlns:local="clr-namespace:iut1.Views"
         mc:Ignorable="d" d:DesignWidth="630" Height="587"
         xmlns:w="clr-namespace:iut1.Classes"
         DataContext="{Binding Path=MainWindowViewModel, Source={StaticResource Locator}}">

<Grid Margin="15,22,0,0">
    <GroupBox Header="Migration de modèle de lettre" Margin="6,10,0,32">
        <Grid Margin="0,0,0,4">
            <Label x:Name="lblChoixPPP" Content="PPP :" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="19,13,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top"/>
            <ComboBox x:Name="cbxChoixPPP" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="67,13,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="120"/>
            <DataGrid x:Name="dgModeles" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="19,61,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Height="162" Width="565">
                <DataGrid.Columns>
                    <DataGridCheckBoxColumn Header=""/>
                    <DataGridTextColumn Header="Numéro de référence" Width="150" />
                    <!--Binding="{Binding Nom}"-->
                    <DataGridTextColumn Header="Titre du modèle de lettre" />
                    <!--Binding="{Binding Prenom}"-->
                </DataGrid.Columns>
            </DataGrid>
            <Label x:Name="lblRechercher" Content="Rechercher :" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="19,239,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top"/>
            <TextBox x:Name="textBox" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="23" Margin="91,241,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="TextBox" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="291"/>
            <Button x:Name="btnAfficherTout" Content="Afficher tout" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="387,244,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="96"/>
            <Button x:Name="btnAfficherSelection" IsEnabled="False" Content="Afficher sélection" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="488,244,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="96"/>
            <DataGrid x:Name="dataGrid" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="19,319,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Height="162" Width="565">
                <DataGrid.Columns>
                    <DataGridTextColumn Header="Résultat de la copie" Width="150" />
                    <DataGridTextColumn Header="" />
                </DataGrid.Columns>
            </DataGrid>
            <ProgressBar HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="20" Margin="22,509,0,-26" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="464"/>
            <Button x:Name="btnDetails" Height="20" IsEnabled="False" Content="Détails" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="491,509,0,-26" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="96"/>
        </Grid>
    </GroupBox>
</Grid>
```

I would like to enable=true my view after click on the Login button on my ConnexionView.
I tryed a lot of thing and nothing works.

MY VM Code :

```
using GalaSoft.MvvmLight.CommandWpf;
using iut1.Classes;
using iut1.Interfaces;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Linq;
using System.Security;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Input;

namespace iut1.ViewModels
{
/// <summary>
/// 
/// </summary>
public class MainWindowViewModel : BaseViewModel, INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    #region Proprietes privées
    private readonly DelegateCommand<string> _clickCommand;



    private string _idUtilisateur;
    private string _passwordUtilisateur;
    private string _environnementSource;
    #endregion Proprietes privées

    #region proprietes publiques
    public string IdUtilisateur
    {
        get { return _idUtilisateur; }
        set
        {
            _idUtilisateur = value;
            RaisePropertyChanged(nameof(IdUtilisateur));
        }
    }
    public string PasswordUtilisateur
    {
        get { return _passwordUtilisateur; }
        set
        {
            _passwordUtilisateur = value;
            RaisePropertyChanged(nameof(PasswordUtilisateur));
        }
    }
    public string EnvironnementSource
    {
        get { return _environnementSource; }
        set
        {
            _environnementSource = value;
            RaisePropertyChanged(nameof(EnvironnementSource));
        }
    }
    #endregion proprietes publiques

    private bool _enabledView;
    public bool EnabledView
    {
        get { return _enabledView; }
        set
        {
            if (_enabledView == value)
            {
                return;
            }

                _enabledView = value;
            RaisePropertyChanged(nameof(EnabledView));
            OnPropertyChanged(nameof(EnabledView));
        }
    }


    public MainWindowViewModel()
    {


        //ButtonCommand = new Classes.RelayCommand(new Action<object> (ConnectionBase));
        ButtonCommand = new Classes.RelayCommand(o => { ConnectionBase(); }, o => true);


        //_clickCommand = new DelegateCommand<string>(
        //    (s) => { ConnectionBase(); /* perform some action */ }
        //    );

        EnabledView =false;
    }


    public DelegateCommand<string> ButtonClickCommand
    {
        get { return _clickCommand; }
    }



    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    private void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
    {
        if (PropertyChanged != null)
        {
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
    }


    private void ConnectionBase()
    {
        if (Validation.ValidationConnection(IdUtilisateur, PasswordUtilisateur, EnvironnementSource))
        {
            EnabledView = true;
            OnPropertyChanged(nameof(EnabledView));

        }
        else
        {
            string msgErreur = "KO";
        }
    }



    private void Login(object parameter)
    {


        //return Validation.ValidationConnection(IdUtilisateur,     password, "ENV");

    }


    private ICommand _buttonCommand;
    public ICommand ButtonCommand
    {
        get
        {
            return _buttonCommand;
        }
        set
        {
            _buttonCommand = value;
        }
    }


}
}
```

The problem is that my view nerver become enable and I'm becoming crazy about that.

Thank you in advance for the help.

Comment: 1. can you show the content of your `RaisePropertyChanged` method.

2. can you confirm, that your `MainWindowViewModel` class implements the INotifyPropertyChanged interface?

3. can you confirm, that a parent of the `Grid` has an instance of `MainWindowViewModel` set as `DataContext`?

Comment: I update my post with the entire code of my VM

Comment: Firstly, you are using `OnPropertyChanged` multiple times in different places, see my comment on the answer below and let's clean up your code.

Comment: I'm sorry but I don't really understanding the way do your set accessor,

Comment: http://www.mvvmlight.net/help/WP8/html/4162331c-43b6-7806-f488-8f6426aa0304.htm

Comment: Is it possible you to modify my property with your example in this link? I'm really beginner with MVVM, and I don't really understand this syntax...

Comment: @Jaymz1982 see below

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is important that you raise the `INotifyPropertyChanged` event once, and in the correct place, so that all 'subscribers' are aware of the old value and the change to the new value. Because you are raising the event multiple times, I suspect that the 'subscribers' are basically being told that the value has been updated - old value: false, new value: false.

Without seeing the entirety of your solution and latest code, it is tough to accurately diagnose the problem, here is code which I have just refactored from what you have in your original post, clicking the button calls the `ButtonCommand` which immediately sets the `EnabledView` property to the opposite of what it currently is, this enables and disables the MigrationModeleView for me.

App.xaml

```
<Application x:Class="MvvmLight1.App"
         xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:vm="clr-namespace:MvvmLight1.ViewModel"
             xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
             xmlns:ignore="http://www.galasoft.ch/ignore"
             StartupUri="MainWindow.xaml"
             mc:Ignorable="d ignore">
    <Application.Resources>
        <!--Global View Model Locator-->
        <vm:ViewModelLocator x:Key="Locator"
                             d:IsDataSource="True" />
    </Application.Resources>
</Application>
```

MainWindow

```
<Window x:Class="MvvmLight1.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:ignore="http://www.galasoft.ch/ignore"
        xmlns:mvvmLight1="clr-namespace:MvvmLight1"
        mc:Ignorable="d ignore"
        Height="650"
        Width="950"
        Title="MVVM Light Application"
        DataContext="{Binding Main, Source={StaticResource Locator}}">

    <Window.Resources>
        <ResourceDictionary>
            <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
                <ResourceDictionary Source="Skins/MainSkin.xaml" />
            </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
        </ResourceDictionary>
    </Window.Resources>

    <Grid>
        <Viewbox Name="vbxConnexion" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="623" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="224">
            <mvvmLight1:ConnexionView></mvvmLight1:ConnexionView>
        </Viewbox>
        <Viewbox Name="vbxContenu" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="233,0,0,0" Width="682" VerticalAlignment="Top"  RenderTransformOrigin="0.5,0.5" Height="620" Stretch="None">
            <mvvmLight1:MigrationModeleView IsEnabled="{Binding EnabledView}" Height="623" Width="653" ></mvvmLight1:MigrationModeleView>
        </Viewbox>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

ConnexionView.xaml

```
<UserControl x:Class="MvvmLight1.ConnexionView"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
             xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
             xmlns:local="clr-namespace:MvvmLight1"
             mc:Ignorable="d" 
             d:DesignHeight="720" d:DesignWidth="240"
             DataContext="{Binding Main, Source={StaticResource Locator}}">
    <Grid Margin="10,30,-13,-18">

        <GroupBox x:Name="gpbSource" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="6,10,0,386" Width="220" Header="Environnement source" Background="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.ScrollBarBrushKey}}" >
            <Grid Margin="0,0,0,20">
                <!--<Rectangle Fill="#FFF4F4F5" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="317" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="220" RadiusY="5" RadiusX="5" Stroke="Black" Opacity="0.1" Margin="0,5,0,0"/>-->
                <Label x:Name="lblIdentifiant" Content="Identifiant de l'utilisateur :" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="4,24,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="200"/>

                <TextBox x:Name="txtNomUsager" Text="{Binding IdUtilisateur}" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="23" Margin="4,48,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="200" AutomationProperties.IsRequiredForForm="True" BorderThickness="2">
                </TextBox>

                <Label x:Name="Password" Content="Mot de passe :" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="4,80,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="200"/>
                <PasswordBox x:Name="txtMotDePasse"  HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="23" Margin="4,103,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="200"/>
                <RadioButton x:Name="rdbUnit" IsChecked="{Binding Path=EnvironnementSource, Mode=TwoWay, ConverterParameter=Unitaire}" GroupName="envSource" Width="79" Content="Unitaire" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="4,160,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top"/>
                <RadioButton x:Name="rdbFonctionnel" IsChecked="{Binding Path=EnvironnementSource, Mode=TwoWay, ConverterParameter=Fonctionnel}" Content="Fonctionnel" GroupName="envSource" Width="79" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="4,183,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top"/>
                <RadioButton x:Name="rdbIntegre" IsChecked="{Binding Path=EnvironnementSource, Mode=TwoWay, ConverterParameter=Integre}" GroupName="envSource" Width="79" Content="Intégré" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="4,206,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top"/>
                <RadioButton x:Name="rdbAcceptation" IsChecked="{Binding Path=EnvironnementSource, Mode=TwoWay, ConverterParameter=Acceptation}" GroupName="envSource" Width="90" Content="Acceptation" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="114,162,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top"/>
                <RadioButton x:Name="rdbFormation" IsChecked="{Binding Path=EnvironnementSource, Mode=TwoWay, ConverterParameter=Formation}" GroupName="envSource" Width="90" Content="Formation" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="114,183,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top"/>
                <RadioButton x:Name="rdbProduction" IsChecked="{Binding Path=EnvironnementSource, Mode=TwoWay, ConverterParameter=Production}" GroupName="envSource" Width="90" Content="Production" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="114,206,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top"/>
                <Button x:Name="Login" Content="Connexion" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="4,252,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="200" Command="{Binding ButtonCommand}"/>
            </Grid>
        </GroupBox>

        <!--<Rectangle Fill="#FFF4F4F5" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="317" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="220" RadiusY="5" RadiusX="5" Stroke="Black" Opacity="0.1" Margin="0,350,0,-179"/>-->
        <GroupBox Width="220"  Header="Environnement source" Margin="6,338,17,57" IsEnabled="False" Background="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.ScrollBarBrushKey}}">
            <Grid Margin="0,0,0,20">
                <Label x:Name="lblIdentifiantCopie" Content="Identifiant de l'utilisateur :" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="4,24,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="200"/>
                <TextBox x:Name="txtNomUsagerCopie" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="23" Margin="4,47,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="200"/>
                <Label x:Name="lblMotDePasseCopie" Content="Mot de passe :" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="4,80,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="200"/>
                <PasswordBox x:Name="txtMotDePasseCopie" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="23" Margin="4,103,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="200"/>
                <RadioButton x:Name="rdbUnitCopie"  Width="79" Content="Unitaire" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="4,160,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top"/>
                <RadioButton x:Name="rdbFonctionnelCopie"  Width="79" Content="Fonctionnel" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="4,183,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top"/>
                <RadioButton x:Name="rdbIntegreCopie"  Width="79" Content="Intégré" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="4,206,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top"/>
                <RadioButton x:Name="rdbAcceptationCopie" Width="90" Content="Acceptation" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="114,162,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top"/>
                <RadioButton x:Name="rdbFormationCopie"  Width="90" Content="Formation" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="114,183,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top"/>
                <RadioButton x:Name="rdbProductionCopie"   Width="90" Content="Production" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="114,206,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top"/>
                <Button x:Name="btnAjout" Content="Ajouter dans l'environnement" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="4,252,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="200"/>
            </Grid>
        </GroupBox>
    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

MigrationModeleView.xaml

```
<UserControl x:Class="MvvmLight1.MigrationModeleView"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
             xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
             xmlns:local="clr-namespace:MvvmLight1"
             mc:Ignorable="d" d:DesignWidth="630" Height="587"
             DataContext="{Binding Main, Source={StaticResource Locator}}">
    <Grid Margin="15,22,0,0">
        <GroupBox Header="Migration de modèle de lettre" Margin="6,10,0,32">
            <Grid Margin="0,0,0,4">
                <Label x:Name="lblChoixPPP" Content="PPP :" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="19,13,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top"/>
                <ComboBox x:Name="cbxChoixPPP" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="67,13,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="120"/>
                <DataGrid x:Name="dgModeles" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="19,61,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Height="162" Width="565">
                    <DataGrid.Columns>
                        <DataGridCheckBoxColumn Header=""/>
                        <DataGridTextColumn Header="Numéro de référence" Width="150" />
                        <!--Binding="{Binding Nom}"-->
                        <DataGridTextColumn Header="Titre du modèle de lettre" />
                        <!--Binding="{Binding Prenom}"-->
                    </DataGrid.Columns>
                </DataGrid>
                <Label x:Name="lblRechercher" Content="Rechercher :" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="19,239,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top"/>
                <TextBox x:Name="textBox" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="23" Margin="91,241,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="TextBox" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="291"/>
                <Button x:Name="btnAfficherTout" Content="Afficher tout" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="387,244,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="96"/>
                <Button x:Name="btnAfficherSelection" IsEnabled="False" Content="Afficher sélection" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="488,244,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="96"/>
                <DataGrid x:Name="dataGrid" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="19,319,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Height="162" Width="565">
                    <DataGrid.Columns>
                        <DataGridTextColumn Header="Résultat de la copie" Width="150" />
                        <DataGridTextColumn Header="" />
                    </DataGrid.Columns>
                </DataGrid>
                <ProgressBar HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="20" Margin="22,509,0,-26" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="464"/>
                <Button x:Name="btnDetails" Height="20" IsEnabled="False" Content="Détails" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="491,509,0,-26" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="96"/>
            </Grid>
        </GroupBox>
    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

MainViewModel.cs

```
using GalaSoft.MvvmLight;
using GalaSoft.MvvmLight.Command;

namespace MvvmLight1.ViewModel
{
    /// <summary>
    /// This class contains properties that the main View can data bind to.
    /// <para>
    /// See http://www.mvvmlight.net
    /// </para>
    /// </summary>
    public class MainViewModel : ViewModelBase
    {
        public MainViewModel()
        {
        }

        public RelayCommand ButtonCommand
        {
            get { return new RelayCommand(() => { EnabledView = !EnabledView; }); }
        }

        private bool _environmentSource;

        public bool EnvironnementSource
        {
            get { return _environmentSource; }
            set { Set(ref _environmentSource, value); }
        }

        private string _idUtilisateur;
        public string IdUtilisateur
        {
            get { return _idUtilisateur; }
            set { Set(ref _idUtilisateur, value); }
        }

        private bool _enabledView;
        public bool EnabledView
        {
            get { return _enabledView; }
            set { Set(ref _enabledView, value); }
        }
    }
}
```

ViewModelLocator.cs

```
using GalaSoft.MvvmLight;
using GalaSoft.MvvmLight.Ioc;
using Microsoft.Practices.ServiceLocation;

namespace MvvmLight1.ViewModel
{
    /// <summary>
    /// This class contains static references to all the view models in the
    /// application and provides an entry point for the bindings.
    /// <para>
    /// See http://www.mvvmlight.net
    /// </para>
    /// </summary>
    public class ViewModelLocator
    {
        static ViewModelLocator()
        {
            ServiceLocator.SetLocatorProvider(() => SimpleIoc.Default);
            SimpleIoc.Default.Register<MainViewModel>();
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Gets the Main property.
        /// </summary>
        [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Performance",
            "CA1822:MarkMembersAsStatic",
            Justification = "This non-static member is needed for data binding purposes.")]
        public MainViewModel Main
        {
            get
            {
                return ServiceLocator.Current.GetInstance<MainViewModel>();
            }
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Cleans up all the resources.
        /// </summary>
        public static void Cleanup()
        {
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much.
I tryed to make my code looking like yours, but nothing changes,.
Is it possible that it don't work because my Login button is IN a view and my usercontrol is in an other view?
Both with the same VM?

Comment: Please check my updated post. Could you update your original post with the XAML code for both views?

Comment: I put your code in mine, but it still don't work...
Did you ever tried to do that in 2 differents view, like me?

Comment: If your views use the same instance of the View Model then it should be fine, but as I can't see your xaml views then I can't say for certain. Again, please update the original post with both of your view files for me to give an accurate answer here.

Comment: I just updated my code with the xaml of the 2 views.

Comment: See the update again, I've added a UserControl which is bound to the same ViewModel, `IsEnabled` works fine

Comment: THank you again for your time, but I really don't what the f*** happen, but it don't work in my solution...
I really don't understand what's the difference between ours solutions...
My userControls are each in a viewbox, i don't think that is a problem..

Comment: Have you checked to see if your validation method is running and the value is indeed being set to `true`?

Comment: Yes I have checked and my property return True.

Comment: Can you post your `MigrationModeleView` XAML?

Comment: I just create your solution with all your code, and it doesn't work in my solution when I click the button.. Ok for the migrationModelView I post it in 2 minutes.

Comment: It's posted for the MigrationModelView

Comment: Thansk, but I don't see your updates. Did you forgot to put the MainViewModel.cs code? This is the ViewModelLocator below this name.

Comment: Updated to include ViewModelLocator, my apologies

Comment: OK, no problem.
Do this solution is working on your side?
You already gave me your ViewModelLocator, a few time ago. :)Di you make changes in the View or the MainVieModel?
I'm completely lost, sorry...

Comment: Let's move this to Chat http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/129567/enabled-view-after-login-my-application

Comment: I can't chat, I have no 20 reputation on the site. I see what you write but I can answer you.

Comment: Create a new temporary project using the code I have provided in the answer, once it works then compare yours and the new project and see where the differences are.

Comment: Big progress!!!! In my new solution with your code, It works fine.
Now I will put or make functions like in my first solution to make it works normally.
Thank you very very much for your patience and your time, you're a boss :)

Have a good day.